# How to Spring 3.2 + hibernate 4 on javaconfig correctly

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-java-config

I want to make test in Spring 3.2 + Hibernate 4 + javaconfig

Content of build.gradle is the next:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'

ext.springVersion =       '3.2.4.RELEASE'
ext.springMobileVersion = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
ext.thymeleafVersion =    '2.0.19'
ext.aspectJVersion =      '1.6.9'
ext.cglibVersion =        '2.2'
ext.slf4jVersion =        '1.6.1'
ext.servletJstlVersion =  '1.2'
ext.servletApiVersion =   '3.0.1'
ext.servletJspVersion =   '2.1'
ext.junitVersion =        '4.11'
ext.tomcatVersion =       '7.0.42'
ext.pgsqlVersion =        '9.1-901.jdbc4'
ext.mockiteoCoreVersion = '1.9.5'
ext.mailVersion         = '1.4.7'
ext.dataBindVersion     = '2.2.3'
ext.hbVersion           = '4.2.7.Final'
ext.guavaVersion        = '15.0'
ext.javassistVersion    = '3.18.0-GA'

war {
    webInf {
        include "src/main/webapp/resources/**"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion") {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:$springMobileVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"

    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$dataBindVersion"
    compile "javax.mail:mail:$mailVersion"
    compile "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:$thymeleafVersion"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:$aspectJVersion"
    compile "cglib:cglib-nodep:$cglibVersion"
    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"
    compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:$servletJstlVersion"
    providedCompile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletApiVersion")
    providedCompile("javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:$servletJspVersion")

    // Persistence
    compile "postgresql:postgresql:$pgsqlVersion"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hbVersion"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:$hbVersion"
    compile "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:$tomcatVersion"
    compile "org.javassist:javassist:$javassistVersion"

    // Tools
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"

    // TEST
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockiteoCoreVersion"
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3"
    testCompile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1"

    // TOMCAT
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:$tomcatVersion",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:$tomcatVersion")
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:$tomcatVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

PersistenceConfig content is the next:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:pgsql.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.persistence"})
public class PersistenceConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.persistence.domain" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation()
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

ProductServiceTest content is the next:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})
public class ProductServiceTest
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductServiceTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public final void listApplicationBeans() throws Exception
    {
        List<String> beans = Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames());
        for (String bean: beans)
        {
            LOG.info(String.format("--> App Beans [%s]", bean));
        }
    }
}
```

persistence.properties content is the next:

```
# jdbc
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://some_address:5432/some_database
jdbc.user=someuser
jdbc.pass=somepassword

# hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Product content is the next:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Product(String name)
    {
        setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(Product.class.getSimpleName()).append(" [\n");
        builder.append("id = ").append(id).append("\n");
        builder.append("name = ").append(name).append("\n");
        builder.append("]");

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

ProductDao content is the next:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.persistence.dao.common.AbstractDao;
import com.example.persistence.domain.Product;
@Repository
public class ProductDao extends AbstractDao<Product>
{
    public ProductDao()
    {
        super();
        setClazz(Product.class);
    }
}
```

ProductService content is the next:

```
@Service
public class ProductService extends AbstractService<Product>
{
    @Autowired
    private ProductDao dao;

    public ProductService()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected IOperation<Product> getDao()
    {
        return dao;
    }
}
```

Result of **gradle clean test**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao com.example.persistence.service.impl.ProductService.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao com.example.persistence.service.impl.ProductService.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Are you sure your `ProductDao` class is annotated with `@Repository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem with my Spring Hibernate project in my test suites.

The only way I could solve the problem was to autowire the class by using its super class as its type (`AbstractService` in your case) and then use a `@Qualifier` to tell Spring which child class I am referring to. It will look something like this in your case:

```
@Qualifier("ProductService")
@Autowired
private AbstractService productService;
```

It is painful as then in the test function you have to cast `productService` object to `ProductService` every time you use a method that belongs to the child class. So if you have already solved this using another solution please share it with us.

Answer (score 2):

**According to the stacktrace:**

```
Could not autowire field: private com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao
com.example.persistence.service.impl.ProductService.dao; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
```

When I found such issue I eliminate the following:

1. The bean is not annotated or not covered by component scan.
   You defined
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.persistence"})
   It covers your package com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao
   *Look’s fine here.*
2. Make sure annotations are correct: ProductDao is annotated @Repository
   *Looks ok.*
3. Make sure that com.example.persistence.dao.impl.ProductDao is in the classpath.
   You are executing the command **gradle clean test**, which means your code will be compiled before  test execution (as test depend on the compile task).
   *If it compiles I guess that ProductDao is in your classpath*
4. Make sure that the JUnit has the required configuration for bootstrapping
   spring application context.
   @ContextConfiguration
   class points to your configurations class. 
   loader attribute was not defined so spring will use the default DelegatingSmartContextLoader (no @WebAppConfiguration in your configuration and version >3.2).
   *Looks good to me.*

Unfortunately I cannot find any issue and everything looks fine (I hope this check list will help someone).
So I would guess that the issue is somewhere in the missing details; like you have to class of ProductDao under  different packages and you are using the wrong one in the ProductService or the wrong interface etc.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I share with you an example of my Hibernate java configuration.
I hope you love it:

Pre-requirement: pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POSTGRESQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Step 1: application.properties

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/curso_db
jdbc.username=alumno
jdbc.password=alumno

#################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true

packagesToScan=com.curso.online.model
```

Step 2: Config.java

```
package com.curso.online;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.curso.online")
public class Config {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String KEY_DRIVER_CLASS;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String KEY_JDBC_URL;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String KEY_JDBC_USERNAME;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String KEY_JDBC_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String KEY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String KEY_HBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${packagesToScan}")
    private String KEY_ENTITIES_PKG;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(KEY_ENTITIES_PKG);
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", KEY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", KEY_HBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(KEY_DRIVER_CLASS);
        dataSource.setUrl(KEY_JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(KEY_JDBC_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(KEY_JDBC_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```